# Why named splats is not working in Julia?

Tags: julia

How to make code below to work?

```
function configure(; options...) println(options) end

configure(a = 1, b = 2, c = 3)

options = (c = 2, b = 3)
configure(options...)

options = (c = 2, b = 3)
configure(a = 1, options...)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because the semicolon matters here.

```
configure(;options...)

configure(;a = 1, options...)
```